# Using user role information with hook_user_logout()

Tags: 7, users, hooks

I want to give users a custom logout message based on their role, but on logout the `$user` variable is no longer available.

How can I achieve this?  I figured the key might be with $_SESSION, during login, but I am not sure exactly how to store user role in the session.

Comment: There are a couple of gotchas in this; you _do_ have the account object, with the roles, in hook_user_logout, but if you set a message it'll perish along with the session when logout completes. Fortunately it's a simple workaround: https://api.drupal.org/comment/43698#comment-43698

Comment: Another reason to love [cookies](http://www.eatfunfoods.com/img-Choc_Chip_Stack_Sidecookie.png)